# Databricks structured streaming with Azure Event Grid

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Can anyone point me to documentation or examples that demonstrate how to use Azure Event Grid as a source for Databricks structured streaming? I found some information on Azure Event Hubs but that is not Azure Event Grid. I also found examples using Apache Kafka but that doesn't translate to AEG.

I found examples for Event Hub but my requirements are for Event Grid.

Comment: Have you tried any approach? And facing any error? Add those details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connector for Spark to consume directly from Event Grid, but you can route messages from Event Grid to EventHubs as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-event-hubs), and then consume from EventHubs using Spark (prefer to use Kafka connector that is built-in into Databricks Runtime).